# Search bar below search button - on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am developing webpages for angular 4 application using bootstrap 3.

Trying to add a search button (top right/top left) which will expand in next row on click. [Refer top right corner search button here.](https://bootsnipp.com/)

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  <form id="demo-2" style="margin-left: 10px">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
input {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,

input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 7px 9px 7px 17px;
  width: 55px;

  border-radius: 1em;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 170px;
  background-color: #fff;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}

#demo-2 input[type=search] {
  width: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#demo-2 input[type=search]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
  color: black;
}
#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

This gives me search bar expand in same row. I've tried to get examples for the same. But all of them talk about expanding same row.

NOTE: The search bar & search button will be in same row for desktop view. [Similar to this](http://hill-laboratories.staging.room9.co.nz/). Will change responsively to mobile view.

Thanks in advance. Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The search button doesn't really get expanded on the next row, it toggles a new element that's positioned underneath it. Check out the examples below to see what I mean.

**Option 1 (with simple JQuery code)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-search").click(function(){
        $(".search-input").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="toggle-search"> Search </button>
<div class="container">
  <form class="row search-input" id="demo-2" style="margin-left: 10px">
    <input class="col-lg-12" type="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Option 2 (doesn't include additional JQuery Code but still requires the JQuery Library)**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".search-input"> Search </button>
<div class="container collapse search-input">
  <form class="row" id="demo-2" style="margin-left: 10px">
    <input class="col-lg-12" type="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I want to achieve it without JQuery/Javascript. Is it possible to do it with Bootstrap/ng-module & angular4!!

Comment: This is also achievable using the javascript that comes with Bootstrap (bootstrap.min.js), would that be okay to use? Otherwise the search field will be toggleable based on screen size, not click.

Comment: I tried your example in my angular application(in HTML with script in **<script>**). No clue where I missed, it just shows me <input> before I click on search button.. Yeah typescript/javascript would be better to do with Angular application. As each component has .css, .html, .ts for it, we don't need to edit **bootstrap.min.js** I believe..

Comment: I know we don't need to edit bootstrap.min.js. What I meant was, would you be okay adding properties that uses this file or do you want it purely with CSS.

Comment: ohh cool. Yes using "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" would be great.

Comment: Please check out the second option. The JQuery file from Bootstrap is still required but no additional JQuery code is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did u make additional changes in CSS file? or its same what I posted in question? Tried with second option. Nope!! Only Search button is displayed but click event not working. I am trying to figure out whats the issue

Comment: I haven't even included your CSS file, let me do that real quick to see if it still works. Also, I've been using Bootstrap 4, hope that doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154112/discussion-between-sheedo-and-vinni).

Comment: Yes, the chat is open. Just click on 'continue this discussion in chat' on my comment to get back to the room, and post any updates over there. I'll be checking back every now and then.